# Return a 404 status code while redirecting users to a custom error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to show users a custom 404 error page but still want to return the error code 404 instead of 302.

However, adding a custom 404 page and redirecting users to it changes the status code to 302. I still want the page to send a 404 status code. Is this possible by making any changes to the `.htaccess` file or using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to generate http 404 error from php can be done by this function

```
http_response_code(404);
```

For reference [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Answer (score 2):

Jasinth ist right. When you redirecting your user (regardless of intension), then it is defacto a 302.

Just for completeness, a 404 can be archived as well through using the `header()` function, i. e.:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

(taken from [PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php))